# Need to find the closest greater number in a list filtered by a numeric value in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to create an Excel formula that would do the following operation:

Whenever there is a particular number in the column `Number` then then the formula should compare the corresponding value in `Target` column with the value in `Code` column and flag in the `Expected Output` all rows, where `Code` greater and nearest value in column `Target`.

[image: Closest greater number]

Comment: Take a deep breath and try to rephrase your question please. It is not clear what you're asking.

Comment: That is so very unclear. But I think I understand you. It is only possible with a VBA user defined function. But since you have never accepted any answer(s) previously given to you...this comment is as much as I will be doing.

Comment: @RusanKax I do not understand either of both parts of your comment. 1) I see accepted answers in 5 of 4 questions of this user. 2) As you see in my answer, it can be done quite well with array MIN(IF( formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe could be easily done in SQL database lanuguage using the `GROUP BY` statement.

You need formula and Excel does not directly support this, because it is not an SQL database.
However it can be done quite easily with formulas. There are more ways how to achieve that, I can show you, how I would do it. I have used array formula `MIN(IF(...` which works in a similiar way as `SELECT MIN(A) FROM range GROUP BY B`

I would create 2 helper columns (D and E) - they could be eventually placed on a separate sheet, if necessary - see picture bellow.

- In the column D place formula: `=IF(B1-C1>0,B1-C1,65535)` (65535 is a little hack for a relatively very high number)
- In the column E place formula: `=MIN(IF(A$1:A$12=A1,D$1:D$12))`**as array formula Ctrl+Shift+Enter** A$1:A$12 and D$1:D$12 are ranges of your data
- In the column F you get your `Expected output`: `=IF(E1=D1,1,0)`

So in the column E you get minimum difference between C and B that is > 0 filtered by A.

[image: Excel example]

When working with Excel data in this way I recommend using named ranges instead of A$1:A$12 etc.

Comment: Typo in `MIN(IF(A$1:A$12=A1;D$1:D$12))`

Comment: Thanks for reply but it is not what I'm expecting.Let me explain in detail.In excel Operation Should be in Column A A1:A6 numbers are matched so in Column B in List B1:B6 it will check nearest value of 3 As mentioned in Column C.And Once it get the value in Column D it flag like D3 & D4 1 and remaining all are 0. And above operation will continue in B7:B12.Remove E and F Column here.

Comment: @user3172930 As far as I understand the problem is the presence of 2 additional columns. I doubt it can be achieved with a single formula without any helper columns or VBA code. You can make theese colums hidden or put them on a different and hidden sheet - I do not see anything wrong with it.

Comment: So what will be the formula for above problem

Comment: @user3172930 It seems I did not understand well. Is there anything wrong with values in Column F - Expected Output? If yes, please post somewhere a sample screenshot with more data and mark where there is value 0 and should be 1 etc.

Comment: In Column F values are right I want the formula in excel to get it

Comment: I think the answer is quite clear but download http://www.filedropper.com/formula_1 - it is excel sheet with formulas I have just uploaded for you, so you can see if it is ok.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60389/discussion-between-vdohnal-and-user3172930).

Comment: I got the Answer.Provided Excel really Helpful.Thanks :D Appreciated